# Problems implementing TokenProvider for CloudFoundry Java CLI

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am developing a microservice that is responsible for starting other microservices running on CloudFoundry. Therefore I make use of the cf-java-client (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client). In our environment we have a special mechanism for authenticating machine users on CloudFoundry:
I have to give a client id and secret to a certain endpoint, that returns an authorization code. With this code I can create temporary credentials for CloudFoundry (which live only 60 min). So far I implemented this behaviour the following:

```
  @Bean
  PasswordGrantTokenProvider tokenProvider() {
    final Map<String, String> temporaryCredentialsMap =
        getTemporaryCredentials(clientId, clientSecret);

    return PasswordGrantTokenProvider.builder()
        .username(temporaryCredentialsMap.get("username"))
        .password(temporaryCredentialsMap.get("password"))
        .build();
  }
```

My problem is now that, when the credentials expire, I get a HTTP 401 bad credentials. I was thinking of recreating the bean above. Is this possible? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Just a thought. Maybe use a scoped bean? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes. Not sure the existing scopes are a good fit, but perhaps you could create a custom scope that fits the time window of your credentials. If the token is invalid a new bean is returned, otherwise the same bean is returned with the already valid token.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I gave it a try and it looks promising. I was thinking of a TimedScoped and using it for the PasswordGrantTokenProvider. The scope resets its beans every 60 mins. This way the credentials get recreated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the scope of all cf related beans to prototype scopes and requesting a new bean from the context to refresh credentials.